# Create dictionary to count values per group in a txt file

Tags: python, python-3.x, dictionary, counting

This migh be very easy to implement but I can figure out a good implementation. I am trying to sum the values for different groups in a txt file. Let's say we have a file where each line is as follows:

```
------------------------
Blank line
class 1 
value 10
------------------------
Blank line
class 2
value 20
------------------------
Blank line
class 1 
value 15
------------------------
Blank line
class 1 
value 20
------------------------
Blank line
class 2
value 10
```

I was thinking in create a dictionary setting the class as keys and sum of values for each key as dictionary value. For instance, the output should be:

`my_dict = {'class 1': 45, 'class 2': 30}`. I made a previous examination of the dataset and realized that there is 500 different classes with different sum of values of course. My first though was using a dictionary for this purpose and don't know if is the best way to do so. What I did was create a dictionary for each line where there is a class but this way I have a lot of dictionaries some of them repeated. But I could sum them by using `Counter fucntion from Collenctions` but definitely this is not the best way.
Any suggestion?

Comment: Are the "Blank line" actually blank lines?

Comment: Are headers but irrelevant indeed

Comment: Post your code please.  The explanation of how you solved the problem is not clear to me.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using regular expressions and a [`defaultdict`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/collections.html#collections.defaultdict):

```
import re
from collections import defaultdict

dct = defaultdict(int)
with open('test.txt') as f:
  data = re.findall(r'(class\s\d+).*\nvalue\s(\d+)', f.read())
  for k, v in data:
    dct[k] += int(v)

print(dct)
```

Output:

```
defaultdict(<class 'int'>, {'class1': 45, 'class2': 30})
```

You can check out the regular expression: [`(class\s\d+).*\nvalue\s(\d+)`](https://regex101.com/r/LCgPfq/2)

I had to add in the `.*` because some of the lines in your input have random whitespace at the end. If that was a copying error you don't need it.